# wso2 api manager analytics pdf report logo not changing

Tags: wso2-api-manager

In wso2 api manager analytics pdf report, I tried to change pdf logo in report, but not changed logo. could you please guide me?

```
wso2am-analytics-3.2.0\wso2\dashboard\deployment\web-ui-apps\analytics-dashboard\public\images

pdf-report-logo.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected.

The PDF Generator uses the `wso2-logo.jpg` placed inside the plugin. Following are the places referring to insert the logo the Report. Therefore, if you change the `pdf-report-logo.jpg`, it will not reflect in the generated reports.

```java
public static void insertLogo(PDDocument document, PDPageContentStream contentStream) throws IOException {

        InputStream in = ReportApiServiceImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("/wso2-logo.jpg");
        PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(document, in);
        contentStream.drawImage(img, 375, 755);
}
```

- [Report Generator | source](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/blob/edd52fd5952730b3f535e89d6936b4a232a93fdd/components/org.wso2.analytics.apim.rest.api.report/src/main/java/org/wso2/analytics/apim/rest/api/report/reportgen/DefaultReportGeneratorImpl.java#L116)
- [Report Util | source](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/blob/edd52fd5952730b3f535e89d6936b4a232a93fdd/components/org.wso2.analytics.apim.rest.api.report/src/main/java/org/wso2/analytics/apim/rest/api/report/reportgen/util/ReportGeneratorUtil.java#L104)
- [Resources | source](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/tree/edd52fd5952730b3f535e89d6936b4a232a93fdd/components/org.wso2.analytics.apim.rest.api.report/src/main/resources)

If you really want to change the image, then, you have to build the plugin with your respective logo image and place it inside the Analytics and try the scenario.

---

#### Update

Find the instructions to build the required components and place them in the Analytics node.

1. Clone the [analytics-apim](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/tree/v3.2.0) repo. The presented link points to the Analytics repo related to 3.2.0
2. Navigate to `analytics-apim/components/org.wso2.analytics.apim.rest.api.report/src/main/resources/` location and replace the `wso2-logo.png` with your logo
3. Execute the following command to build the repo from the root directory of `analytics-apim` (After first build, you can execute the following command from the respective component to build that only and not required to run this again from the root directory)

   ```sh
   mvn clean install package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true
   ```
4. Once the build is finished for the `org.wso2.analytics.apim.rest.api.report 3.2.0`, copy the built JAR artifact from `analytics-apim/components/org.wso2.analytics.apim.rest.api.report/src/target` directory
5. Go to the Analytics node and move to `<analytics_home>/wso2/lib/plugins` directory. Backup the existing `org.wso2.analytics.apim.rest.api.report_3.2.0.jar` and place the newly built JAR artifact. Once placed, rename the JAR to have the same pattern as the backed-up one. (You may wanna update the `-3.2.0` with `_3.2.0`)
6. Start the Dashboard node and try downloading the report

Comment: could you please explain more how to to build the plugin with our logo?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the steps. Hope that helps.